# $\mathrm{Tor}(\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(x,z), \mathbb{C}[x,y,z]/(y,z))$

Tags: commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

I have a question about the problem to compute $\mathrm{Tor}_i^R(M,N)$ for $R=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$, $M=R/(x,z)$, and $N=R/(y,z)$.
(This is an exercise in the [Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0FWR).)

My calculation:

I have the flat resolution $0 → R^2 → R^2 → R → N → 0$, where
$R^2 → R^2$ is $(a,b)→ (az,-by)$,
$R^2 → R$ is $(c,d) → cy+dz$.

Then, $\mathrm{Tor}^R(M,N)$ is the homology of $0 → M^2 → M^2 → M → 0$, where
$M^2 → M^2$ is $(a,b) → (0,-by)$,
$M^2 → M$ is $(c,d) → cy.$

So,
$\mathrm{Tor}^R_0(M,N) = \mathrm{coker}(M^2 → M) = M/yM \cong \mathbb{C}$,
$\mathrm{Tor}^R_1(M,N) = \ker(M^2 → M)/\mathrm{Im}(M^2 → M^2) = (0,M)/(0,yM) \cong \mathbb{C}$, and
$\mathrm{Tor}^R_2(M,N) = \ker(M^2 → M^2) = (M,0) \cong M$.

Similar calculation will give $\mathrm{Tor}_2^R(N,M) \cong N$, but I think it contradicts to the property $\mathrm{Tor}_i^R(M,N) \cong \mathrm{Tor}_i^R(N,M)$ because $M$ and $N$ are not isomorphic $R$-module.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: What are $R$ and $C$?

Comment: @Bernard R=C[x,y,z] and I think C is the complex field. I have edited to change C into \mathbb{C}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image of the map $R^2\to R^2$, $(a,b)\mapsto (az, -by)$, is larger than the kernel of the other map you describe. Try the map $R\to R^2$, $a\mapsto (az,-ay)$ instead.